# Backbone Collection .findwhere() underscore method

Tags: javascript

This code is returning the alert message the number of times models are present in collection. I want to print it just once and come out of the loop as soon as the username and password matches.
what to do?

```
                this.collection.find(function(model)
                {
                     debugger
                     var user = model.get('username');
                     var pwd = model.get('password');

                     if(enteredUsername == user && enteredPassword == pwd)
                     {

                         return(alert("success"));

                     }
                     else
                     {  
                         return(alert("failure"));

                     }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sources of BB

```
    where: function(attrs, first) {
      if (_.isEmpty(attrs)) return first ? void 0 : [];
      return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
        for (var key in attrs) {
          if (attrs[key] !== model.get(key)) return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    },
¶
Return the first model with matching attributes. Useful for simple cases of find.


    findWhere: function(attrs) {
      return this.where(attrs, true);
    },
```

so try

```
console.log(this.collection.findWhere({username: username, password: password}));
```